# Where is SyncLinq?

Tags: c#, linq

In 2007 Paul stovell created this set of extentions. It notifies the UI of changes.  It seems to have disappeared.

What can we use today that mimcs its functionality???

Comment: What exactly does SyncLinq do that you can't do with INotifyPropertyChanged ? Tell us more about what you're trying to do, perhaps there are other options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SyncLinq still exists but has been renamed as [{Bindable LINQ}](http://bindablelinq.codeplex.com/).